# pandas join list elements to other dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframes and I want to join the list column, look up and get the values.

```
df1 
x_id  y_id
1     [101,102,103]
2     [102, 103]
3     [103]

df2
y_id   y_name
101     abc
102     xyz
103     def
```

I want a dataframe df3 as:

```
df3
x_id  y_id             y_names
1     [101,102,103]    [abc, xyz, def]   
2     [102, 103]       [xyz, def]
3     [103]            [def]
```

Tried using lookup and apply functions but couldn't achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first option using a list comprehension and a mapping Series:

```
s = df2.set_index('y_id')['y_name']

df1['y_names'] = [[s[x] for x in l] for l in df1['y_id']]
```

A second option using `explode`, `map` and `groupby.agg`:

```
(df1
 .explode('y_id')
 .assign(y_names=lambda d: d['y_id'].map(df2.set_index('y_id')['y_name']))
 .groupby('x_id', as_index=False).agg(list)
)
```

output:

```
   x_id             y_id          y_names
0     1  [101, 102, 103]  [abc, xyz, def]
1     2       [102, 103]       [xyz, def]
2     3            [103]            [def]
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'y_id': [[101, 102, 103], [102, 103], [103]]})
```

Comment: I'm missing something, the explode doesn't work for me. I was thinking along the same lines of exploding the column first. Any pointers? thanks

Comment: @Naveed it depends on the exact input. I assumed a Series of lists (see update). If not you must convert to a list or use a regex (if strings)

Answer (score 0):

convert df2 to a dictionary for lookup then use a the dataframe apply to get the lookup values from the dictionary